# Can you create an indexed list of all Wolfram functions within a notebook?

Tags: functions, notebooks, core-language, indexing

Can you create a summary list of all Wolfram functions used within a whole notebook? Searched long and hard- no clear documentation found.

Comment: What do you need this for? Just in case there might be a different approach to solve your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by an indexed list? What do you expect the function to retuen and how should it be formatted? Would you accept a list of the symbols used or all the symbols defined int the notebook?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is more of a summary list of Wolfram functions used within the notebook.

Comment: Maybe something like, which culls symbols, including those that might not be considered "functions": ``Union@Cases[ToExpression[NotebookRead[Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Input"]][[All, 1]], StandardForm, HoldComplete], h_Symbol /; Context[h] === "System`", Infinity, Heads -> True]`` for a `NotebookObject` `nb`. It won't list other functions that are called by functions, unless they happen to occur in an input cell.  And it ignores internal functions, user functions, and package functions.

Comment: This was great, very helpful for my project.

Comment: For completeness before the above code for summaries of functions within the working notebook-nb = InputNotebook[]